# Equivalent of `takeWhile` for Spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,.5), (2,.3), (3,.9), (4,.0), (5,.6), (6,.0)).toDF("id", "x")
scala> df.show()
+---+---+
| id|  x|
+---+---+
|  1|0.5|
|  2|0.3|
|  3|0.9|
|  4|0.0|
|  5|0.6|
|  6|0.0|
+---+---+
```

I would like to take the first rows of the data as long as the `x` column is nonzero (note that the dataframe is sorted by `id` so talking about the first rows is relevant). For this given dataframe, it would give something like that:

```
+---+---+
| id|  x|
+---+---+
|  1|0.5|
|  2|0.3|
|  3|0.9|
+---+---+
```

I only kept the 3 first rows, as the 4th row was zero.

For a simple `Seq`, I can do something like `Seq(0.5, 0.3, 0.9, 0.0, 0.6, 0.0).takeWhile(_ != 0.0)`. So for my dataframe I thought of something like this:

```scala
df.takeWhile('x =!= 0.0)
```

But unfortunately, the `takeWhile` method is not available for dataframes.

I know that I can transform my dataframe to a `Seq` to solve my problem, but I would like to avoid gathering all the data to the driver as it will likely crash it.

The `take` and the `limit` methods allow to get the `n` first rows of a dataframe, but I can't specify a predicate. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: `takeWhile` isn't straightforward to implement efficiently with distributed data. You could do something like this. First, `df.where($"x" === 0.0).select(min("id"))` should give your the `id` where `x` is first zero, let's call it `first_id`. Then `df.where($"id" < first_id)` will select the desired subset. There is probably some clever trick with window functions that can do it in a single line...

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't think of that. I came up with another solution: I compute `df.rdd.toLocalIterator.takeWhile(_.getAs[Double]("x") != 0.0)` that I'll call `newIterator`. Then I just use `spark.createDataFrame(newIterator.toList.asJava, df.schema)`. (It can be done in one line, I splited it into two for clarity.) To be honest my method looks quite heavy in conversions and casting, so yours might be better. What do you think?

Comment: `RDD.toLocalIterator` brings in entire partitions one after another into the driver memory, which may not be desirable. My method requires `collect`-ing the min ID only. It's hard to tell which one is better, honestly, as it depends on many factors.

Comment: After a few performance test with real data, I found my method quite faster than yours (for my specific case). In my data, it is likely that the first zero will not be very long to appear, so I think bringing back the partitions to the driver one by one ends up being faster than filtering all the data. However, for a case in which the first zero can be anywhere in the dataframe, potentially at the end, I think your method will probably be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Can you guarantee that ID's will be in ascending order?  New data is not necessarily guaranteed to be added in a specific order.  If you can guarantee the order then you can use this query to achieve what you want.  It's not going to perform well on large data sets, but it may be the only way to achieve what you are interested in.

We'll mark all 0's as '1' and everything else as '0'.  We'll then do a rolling total over the entire data awr.  As the numbers only increase in value on a zero it will partition the dataset into sections with number between zero's.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy().orderBy("id")
df.select( 
  col("id"), 
  col("x"), 
  sum(  // creates a running total which will be 0 for the first partition --> All numbers before the first 0
    when( col("x") === lit(0), lit(1) ).otherwise(lit(0)) // mark 0's to help partition the data set.
  ).over(windowSpec).as("partition")   
).where(col("partition") === lit(0) )
.show()
---+---+---------+
| id|  x|partition|
+---+---+---------+
|  1|0.5|        0|
|  2|0.3|        0|
|  3|0.9|        0|
+---+---+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you for this other method! I went for another way that was faster for my specific case (see comment on the original question), but your method was quite close in term of performances, it might be better for a more general use case than mine.

Comment: Could you post your faster answer so I can learn from it?

Comment: Did you have a look at the comment I mentioned on the initial question?